# Non-linear correlation (co-dependence) and the efficient frontier

Tags: portfolio-optimization, correlation, modern-portfolio-theory, diversification, nonlinear

The graph below shows how the efficient frontier for 2 assets bends into a sharp bisection as correlation decreases from $1$ to $-1$, with $\rho=-1$ being the most diversified, and highly unattainable since negatively correlated assets are hard to find.

[image: correlation of efficient frontier]

Since correlation $\rho$ only measures linear co-dependency between two assets, the graph is ignoring any non-linear dependence between the same assets, meaning that the true efficient frontier could be very different if based on a non-linear measure, rather than linear $\rho$. How then does the efficient frontier change if we take the non-linear relationship betwen assets $A$ and $B$ into account? What would be a good measure for non-linear dependence, and how would the efficient frontier based on that measure look as its value changes?

Answer (score 3):

What you show here as an efficient frontier for a two-asset portfolio is presumably  the **usual**  return versus risk profile, where the vertical axis represents expected portfolio return $\mathbb{E}(r_P) := \mu_P$ and the horizontal axis represents the standard deviation of portfolio return $\sqrt{var(r_P)} :=\sigma_P$. These quantities are given analytically in terms of $w$, the weight of asset A, and the expected returns $\mu_A, \mu_B$, and the standard deviation of returns, $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$ for the individual assets, according to

$$\tag{*}\sigma_P = w \mu_A + (1-w) \mu_B,\\ \sigma_P^2 = w^2 \sigma_A^2 + (1-w)^2 \sigma_B^2 +2\mathbb{E}[(r_A-\mu_A)(r_B- r_b)] $$

The third term on the right-hand side contributing to $\sigma_P^2$ is the covariance of returns of the individual assets, which by definition of the Pearson correlation coefficient $\rho$ is

$$\mathbb{E}[(r_A-\mu_A)(r_B- r_b)] = \rho \sigma_A \sigma_B$$

It is a mathematical fact that $-1 \leqslant \rho \leqslant 1$, and (*) determines $\mu_P$ and $\sigma_P$ as functions of $w$ and also of $\rho$ (for $\sigma_P$ only).

Hence, with $\mu_A, \mu_B, \sigma_A, \sigma_B$ fixed, the efficient frontier is the locus of points $(\sigma_P(w,\rho), \mu_P(w))$ with the parameter $\rho$ fixed as $w$ varies between $0$ and $1$.

Nothing about the joint return distribution for $r_A$ and $r_B$ other than the means and variances of the marginal distributions and the Pearson correlation was used here.  As long as risk is represented by the standard deviation of portfolio return, then the graph is unchanged regardless of the presence or absence of nonlinear dependency.

**If you want to see something different**, you have to specify (1) a  different measure for risk such as $VaR_\alpha$,  the worst loss that can be expected with a prescribed level of confidence $\alpha$, and (2) introduce a specific joint distribution of returns.

For (2) we could use, for example, a joint return distribution with normal marginal distributions and a dependence structure specified by a (Student's) t copula.  In addition to a correlation parameter $\rho$ there will be a degree-of-freedom parameter $\nu$ which introduces tail dependency as it is varied. Here tail dependency means that the correlation of returns deviates from  $\rho$ when conditioned on extreme returns.

Now your "efficient frontier" would be a surface representing $VaR_\alpha(w,\rho, \nu)$ versus $\mu_P(w)$, parameterized by both $\rho$ and $\nu$.

There is no limit to the number of parameters and model complexity you could introduce here, and the determination of the frontier would no doubt require a numerical procedure.  It is not clear what would be gained.

Comment: no mention of non-linear codependence in this answer. If the t-copula is parameterized by $\rho$, linear correlation, then it too doesn't address non-linearity does it

Comment: @develarist: Is that a statement or a question?  I just said above that the t-copula has an additional parameter, degrees of freedom, that controls tail dependence.  Perhaps you are not familiar with that aspect. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135597/defining-tail-dependence#:~:text=T-copulas%20have%20the%20tail%20dependence%20and%20the%20dependence,thin%20line%20in%20the%20upper-right%20and%20lower-left%20corners)  for some details.   This answer is not just about the details of a t-copula or any other model of non-linear dependence per se.

Comment: you said t-copula is a function of two parameters: $\rho$ and $\nu$. I definitely was not talking about $\nu$. you still haven't addressed non-linearity. if you say this answer is not about any model of non-linear dependence, then this answer doesn't belong to the original question does it

Comment: What non-linearity are you taking about?  Can you describe that in detail?  My answer also points out that your question with unlabeled axes is not even clear about what you mean by efficient frontier.  As I said if that means a plot of standard deviation versus expected return, then nothing changes regardless of nonlinearity.  If you are confused why I labeled the second t-copula parameter $\rho$, then call it something else.

Comment: If you read about how it is constructed in a multivariate setting then there is both a dispersion matrix $\Sigma$ and a DOF parameter.  For a bivariate distribution this involves two parameters $\nu$ and whatever you want to call the second parameter.

Comment: of course the axes are $E(r)$ and $\sigma$, i just got the image from search. and i guess the question is asking help from someone who acknowledges the existence of non-linearity, which you have just shown to not know about

Comment: the last line of the question even says "What would be a good measure for non-linear dependence, and how would the efficient frontier based on that measure look as its value changes?" implying the x-axis can be modified to what you see fit for capturing non-linearity

Comment: let me put it this way. correlation does not measure *all* co-dependence. it only measures *linear* co-dependence. there are many other correlation measures that do detect non-linear dependence including Spearman correlation. which validates the point that there can be non-linear relationships that (Pearson) correlation, which is what the mean-variance model is based, cannot detect

Comment: No, x-axis is *not* return, it's volatility. If VaR captures non-linearity, then explain it

Comment: If I understand you correctly tail dependence as described in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_dependence and its usual metric is not indicative of nonlinearity.  I disagree but let’s move on.  You suggest Spearman correlation as a more appropriate metric. What then do you want the axes of your “efficient frontier” graph to represent as you plot curves with fixed values for Spearman correlation. You did ask above for (1) a good measure of nonlinear dependence and (2) how the efficient frontier graph would change as that measure is varied. What is to be plotted versus what?

Comment: Or if you want the x-axis to represent a parameter of nonlinear dependence, the what is the y-axis (return?) and what other parameters create the level curves or surfaces. My understanding of efficient frontier is that it is return vs risk.

Comment: you are confusing the x axis (horizontal) for the y axis (vertical). good point, returns (vertical axis) could very well be what should be substituted. But $\sigma$, $\rho$ and covariance are all linear measures so my first thought was replacing $\sigma$ on the horizontal axis. Portfolio returns would still be calculable regardless of risk measure. And im not saying Spearman corr is better because its not, which i won't get into here. But it does pick up non-linearity which Pearson can't, that's all. So we are looking for something else. I asked the question so don't ask me for the answer